# Accessing Named Routes in Rakefile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rails-routing

I have some named routes like this `rake routes`:

```
birthdays GET    /birthdays(.:format)                             birthdays#index
```

In a rakefile I simply want to be able to call `birthdays_url` like I would in my view.

```
task :import_birthdays => :environment do
  url = birthdays_url
end
```

But I'm getting an error `undefined local variable or method 'birthdays_url' for main:Object`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can either use this example code in your rake task:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
puts birthdays_url(:host => 'example.com')
```

or you can use this example code in your rake task:

```
puts Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.birthdays_url(:host => 'example.com')
```

If you only want the path part of the URL, you can use `(:only_path => true)` instead of `(:host => 'example.com')`. So, that would give you just `/birthdays` instead of `http://example.com/birthdays`.

You need either the `(:host => 'example.com')` or `(:only_path => true)` piece, because the rake task doesn't know that bit of information and will give this error without it:

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

Comment: I don't like hard coding the host. so I use `host: YOUR-APP-NAME::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host]` That way it picks it up from your config files.

Answer (score 4):

for Rails 4 include code with your domain at the top of your rake task

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
default_url_options[:host] = 'example.com'
```

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.birthdays_url
```

or to be less verbose:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
url = birthdays_url
```